# MediaCodec.stop() occasionally throws "CodecException: Error 0x80000000"

Tags: android-mediacodec

I want to emphasize that this never happens on the vast majority (>99%) of Android devices running the app. On a few devices, it happens occasionally.

```
MediaCodec mediaCodecVideo= MediaCodec.createByCodecName("OMX.google.hevc.decoderOMX.google.hevc.decoder")
mediaCodecVideo.configure(mediaForma, surface, null, 0);
...
mediaCodecVideo.start()
...
mediaCodecVideo.stop()
```

mediaCodecVideo.stop() occasionally throws the following exception:

```
android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Error 0x80000000
        at android.media.MediaCodec.native_stop(MediaCodec.java)
        at android.media.MediaCodec.stop(MediaCodec.java:2435)
```

Could anyone shed some light on the possible causes of this? It seems this error does not affect MediaCodec.release(), so it does not seem to create any problems as long as the exception is caught. I am asking this mainly out of curiosity.

Comment: Are you stopping in a different thread from encoding? It might be because you did not drained the encoder

Comment: @UrielFrankel  There are many threads involved in decoding. The code is fairly complicated (thousands of lines), so it is impractical to post all the code. The app does not involve encoding. The video stream is from a camera's RTSP server.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a shot in the dark, but in my experience, if the last frame before you call stop is a sync frame, there will be crash on some devices. So just print if the last frame before calling stop is a sync frame:

```
if(bufferInfo.flags and MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_KEY_FRAME != 0){
     Log.d(TAG,"last frame was a key frame")
}
encoder.stop()
```

Comment: Thank you. I assume you meant the last decoded frame. I will verify it and report back.

Comment: yes, please let me know. If not I will delete my answer

Comment: I have added an entry in the log to track this and will report back.

Comment: btw you need to call end of stream before you call stop

Comment: Could you tell me how to call end of stream? MediaCodec does not seem to have this method. The app essentially receives broadcasted video streams. They do not end. The video stream ends whenever the user wants to stop viewing it. I have added the entries to the of but am yet to catch 0x80000000. I have caught many IllegalStateExceptions but they are not correlated with BUFFER_FLAG_KEY_FRAME